# return Matlab Command Window to cmd

Tags: matlab, jenkins

I would like to create a Jenkins job which would trigger **Matlab** function. It is easy!

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\matlab.exe -nodisplay -r "disp('Hello World!');exit"
```

The question is how to return the matlab command window.

It is of course cool to start some process, but I need to track it.
Some of you say probably “.log”. I know, but I want to see it alive in Jenkins console.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried calling Matlab with the option `-logfile output.log`? That should dump the whole Command Window Output into the logfile `output.log`. See also [this link to the documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html).

Answer (score 1):

If waiting the matlab process to finish is fine with you, then just add the `-wait -log` switches:

```
"%PATH_TO_MATLAB_BIN%\matlab.exe" -nodisplay -r "disp('Hello World!');exit" -wait -log
```